# How to rendering multiple sub grids or similar UI using ag grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

i need to the below like grid. Could you please help me to render?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMcPY.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need the Master / Detail feature as this enables you to expand a row and have another grid nested.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/master-detail/